# Image bigger that parent div

Tags: html, css

I have some very simple html a div with an image inside. Strangely the image extends beyond the bottom of the div and I cannot understand why.

```
<div>
    <img src="picture.jpg">
</div>
```

When I check the element properties the div has a height of 195px and the image has a height of 200px.

This has me stuck. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

**Edit1**

Looking through the properties I found:

```
img {
  margin-bottom: -5px
}
```

This is set by w3.css:

```
.w3-image{max-width:100%;height:auto}img{margin-bottom:-5px}a{color:inherit}
```

I am not sure why this is being applied as I have no class set for this image or the containing div.

I have now fixed this with:

```
img {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

**edit2**

Ok, found it. the clas was being applied elsewhere. Removed it now and all good.

Answer (score 0):

you coud give an ID to the image and add it to the css file whit a widthof 100%

```
 <div src="img.jpg" id="id_example"></div>
```

***///CSS

```
  #id_example {
     width: 100%;
      }
```

or you can try in pixels

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

For this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <img src="picture.jpg">
</div>
```

Add this CSS code:

```
div img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```